# Get object from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I got a List of Team objects, and one of the properties of a Team is a List of Player objects.

I want to grab a player with a specific ID from a team with a specific ID, for example:

```
Get the player with ID (player.id) 123 from the Team with ID 987 (team.id)
```

How can I do this using LINQ?

Many thanks in advance, Bob

Comment: That's quite straightforward with the [`Where` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
var team = teams.FirstOrDefault(teams => teams.ID == 987);
if(team != null) {
    var result = team.Players.FirstOrDefault(player => player.ID == 123);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple, though

```
var list = new List<Team>();
var playerInTeam = list.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Id==987).Players.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id==123);
```

Or, more general soultion:

```
public Player GetPlayerInTeam(int playerId, int teamId, IEnumerable<Team> teams)
{
    return teams.First(t=>t.Id==teamId).Players.First(p=>p.Id==playerId);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Where` for this. `Single(OrDefault)`, `First(OrDefault)` would be better I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
var teams = new List<team>();
var player_team=teams.First(a=>a.id==987).players.First(b=>b.id==123);
```